# LC prefilter with Damping circuit calculation for LDO

Tags: passive-filter

I need to put LC Prefilter with RC damping circuit before LDO. The input voltage to the LDO is 24V +/- 4V. The values I have selected are as follows

Lf = 10uH
Cf = 22uF
Cd = 220uF
Rd = 1E

I am unable to recognize the power dissipation through the resistor Rd. Kindly provide me the calculation to estimate the power dissipation through the resistor Rd.

The reference circuit is also attached to this question.

[image: LC low pass filter with damping circuit.]

Comment: Tell us more about the circuit that this subcircuit will go into. Why do you need the LC prefilter? Is there a known ripple on the input?

Comment: To answer this question conclusively you would need to know the power spectrum of the input to the filter network. If this is used in a line connected device, you may be able to find some canonical models that are a good estimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we know that we can write:

$$\text{i}_{\text{R}_\text{d}}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\underbrace{\frac{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_\text{f}}}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_\text{f}}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_\text{d}}+\text{R}_\text{d}}}_\text{current divider}\cdot\underbrace{\underbrace{\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{s}}}_\text{input voltage}\cdot\left(\underbrace{\text{sL}_\text{f}+\frac{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_\text{f}}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}_\text{d}}+\text{R}_\text{d}\right)}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_\text{f}}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_\text{d}}+\text{R}_\text{d}}}_\text{input impedance}\right)^{-1}}_\text{input current}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Now, we can use:

$$\text{P}_{\text{R}_\text{d}}\left(t\right)=\text{i}_{\text{R}_\text{d}}^2\left(t\right)\text{R}_\text{d}\tag2$$

Plotting the power for \$\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}=24\space\text{V}\$ (blue), \$\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}=20\space\text{V}\$ (orange) and \$\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}=28\space\text{V}\$ (green) gives:

[image]

The maximum occurs at \$t\approx0.0000470891\space\text{s}\$ and the maximum powers are \$\hat{\text{P}}_{\text{R}_\text{d}}\approx\left\{859.112 ,596.606,1169.35\right\}\space\text{W}\$ respectively.

Comment: Nice, but unlikely that the input voltage is a perfect unit step function.  Not really enough information in the question to be able to answer anything other than steady-state power dissipation is zero.

Comment: Hi Jan! 

Thanks for the answer.

Can you tell me the software used for the analysis? 

It would be great if you tell me that the 250mW resistor will sustain this peak for the given time duration of the 100uS?

Comment: @HW01 You're welcome, I am really glad that you like the answer and that I could help you. I used Wolfram Mathematica. You can find the energy dissipated in the resistor by integrating over the power plotted in the picture. But I think the resistor will be fine.